# Table does not align as expected

Tags: tables, xetex

I'm new to Latex and I don't know if this is something I should know, but I was working with tables and the 2nd one does not align as I would. See example below.

```
\section{Color}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ ccccc }
\hline
& \textbf{Temp} & \textbf{Tint} \
& \textbf{Vibrance} & \textbf{Saturation} \\
\hline
{\textbf{White Balance}} & 0 & 0 & 18 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill \break

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ cccc }
\hline
\textbf{Color Mix} & \textbf{Hue} \
& \textbf{Saturation} & \textbf{Luminance} \\
\hline
{\textbf{Red}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Orange}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Yellow}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Green}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Cyan}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Blue}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Purple}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
{\textbf{Magenta}} & 0 & 3 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is this the output you expect? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lXtf.png

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't know how to display what i wanted

Comment: the indendation of the second one is the normal paragraph indentation. If you don't want it use `\noindent\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: To get the output shown in my previous comment, replace `\hfill \break` with `\medskip` and add `\noindent` right before the second `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: Thank you both, very kind

Comment: Usually a `tabular` in better nested in a `table` where indentations and vertical skips is not a problem. But be aware that a `table`  is a "float" that can be moved  better places automatically. Do not consider this a bug but a feature. You have options to control float placements and consider that inside a `table` and  before `tabular` you can use   `\caption{Whatever\label{foo}}`, so the table will have a numbered title, that you can reference in text  with "see table \ref{foo}" and therefore reader can find the table even if the float must be moved to another page..